# Creating tables in PhpMyAdmin - error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

The code:

```
            delimiter $$

            CREATE TABLE "login" (
              "IdUser" int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              "username" varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
              "pass" varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY ("IdUser")
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

            CREATE TABLE "photos" (
              "IdPhoto" int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              "title" varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
              "IdUser" int(11) NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY ("IdPhoto")
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

Errors:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"login" (
  "IdUser" int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "username" varchar(45)' at line 1 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"photos" ( "IdPhoto" int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "title" varchar(100)' at line 1
```

Any ideas? I'm brand new to this so any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks like this  ` instead of double quotes throughout

For example:

```
`IdUser` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use double quotes in identifiers only if the [`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) SQL mode is enabled.

```
SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c6cb)** demo

Otherwise just use back ticks or nothing at all if your identifiers are not in a reserved words list.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `login` (
  `IdUser` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdUser`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
;

CREATE TABLE `photos` (
  `IdPhoto` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `IdUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdPhoto`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cea5c)** demo

Further reading [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

Answer (score 0):

you should use backticks ` not double quotes  "
like that.

```
     CREATE TABLE `login` (
```

same for other columns.