# SQL syntax error,

Tags: mysql

This small query is driving me crazy. I keep getting errors no matter what I try

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

This is the code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE deposit (
    IN custAccount INT(11),
    IN amount INT(11)
)
IF amount < 0 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid amount';
END IF;
```

The procedure is incomplete, dont judge it yet :D
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703441/mysql-error-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual-that-corresp or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005685/creating-tables-in-phpmyadmin-error-1064 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801489/mysql-error-code-1064-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax . Don't forget to google before asking new questions. (:

Comment: Already tried that and it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

"[The example uses the mysql client delimiter command to change the statement delimiter from ; to // while the procedure is being defined. This enables the ; delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the server rather than being interpreted by mysql itself.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)"